# Error adding user defined plugin (Java Class) IBM Worklight

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using IBM Worklight 6.2 for creating hybrid application. I have created one JavaClass (CheckList.java) in `com.myClass.pkg package`.
and wants to use its function on JavaScript.

But when I access CheckList class I am getting error "ClassNotFound"

Below is the code I wrote.

**Js file**

```
cordova.exec(function() {
    console.log("Success");
    alert('feedback sent');
}, function(error) {
    console.log("error is " + error);
    alert('feedback was not sent');
}, 'CheckList', 'chk', [ 'Hello' ]);
```

**Java class**

CheckList.java in com.myClass.pkg

**Config.xml**

Comment: This line added in config.xml..

<feature name="CheckList">
        <param name="android-package" value="com.tcs.mobility.CheckList" />
    </feature>

Comment: where are you adding your CheckList.java? is it under <App Name > >> Server > Java > com > myClasspkg > Checklist.java? Edit your question to add the config.xml, and don't put it inside a comment. Also please provide your CheckList.java code.

Comment: Please don't mark your questions as urgent here - all questions have the same priority, and it is volunteers who will answer.

Comment: thanks sir..it help me alot...

Answer (score 0):

Java classes that you place in the server\java folder are meant to be accessed by server-side entities such as adapters, so it is no wonder why you would not be able to access it from your client-side code.

If what you're looking for is to actually create a Cordova plug-in, and since you say Java then a Cordova plug-in for Android, be sure you're following the instructions provided here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/adding-native-functionality/android-adding-native-functionality-hybrid-application-apache-cordova-plugin/

There is also a sample to download.